# I have a list of customers, each customer has invoice dates, I am trying to average the dates between customer orders

Tags: google-sheets

I am importing the data from QB, with headers Customer, Date - I am calculating the Days between last purchase and am trying to take the average of those dates. What I am left with is this - How do I take the average of each separate customer?

[image]

Comment: What have you tried? [This may prove useful](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AVERAGE-function-047BAC88-D466-426C-A32B-8F33EB960CF6)

Comment: Are you happy with manually selecting the rows belonging to each customer in order to calculate the average for each one with the `=AVERAGE` function or do you want an automatic detection of where the data for one customer ends and for the next one begins? The latter would be easier to do with a script.

Answer (score 0):

The way I would do it is to add another column to calculate which customer the value relates to, then work out the average.

To do this, insert a column between "Days Btwn Orders" and "Average Days Btwn Orders". We'll call this "Corresponding Customer". The rest assumes "Date" is column B, "Days Btwn orders" is column C and "Corresponding Customer" is column D.

Put this formula into that column, row 2: `=IF(A2<>"",A2,D1)`

Then, put this into row 2 of "Average Days Btwn Orders": `=IF(AND(A2<>"",C2=""),averageifs(C:C,D:D,D2),"")`

Then drag both formulas down as far as you need. There's probably a way to do this in an arrayformula so it doesn't need the extra column.

Comment: Hi James, Thank you for the response! I tried your suggestion - the zeros between the customers get factored into the average. ex - 0,10,20 average should be 15, but it will return 10

Comment: Ah yes, in which case, you can ignore zeros from the average calculation: `=IF(AND(A2<>"",C2=""),averageifs(C:C,D:D,D2,C:C,"<>0"),"")`

Comment: That works!!!.... awesome thank you so much! The only caveat - I had to change C2= " " in the if statement to C2=0 after the initial customer. Thank you very much!